# DAX Measure to Divide row value by filtered row value from same table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables.

```
                  Table 1
```

| Product | Geography | Time | Dollar Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***Sting*** | ***Region 1*** | ***1 Week*** | ***100*** |
| Pepsi | Region 1 | 1 Week | 200 |
| Lays | Region 1 | 1 Week | 500 |
| Sting | Region 2 | 1 Week | 200 |
| Pepsi | Region 2 | 1 Week | 300 |
| Lays | Region 2 | 1 Week | 700 |
| Sting | National | 1 Week | 500 |
| Pepsi | National | 1 Week | 1000 |
| Lays | National | 1 Week | 1600 |
| Sting | Region 1 | YTD | 100 |
| Pepsi | Region 1 | YTD | 200 |
| Lays | Region 1 | YTD | 500 |
| Sting | Region 2 | YTD | 200 |
| Pepsi | Region 2 | YTD | 300 |
| Lays | Region 2 | YTD | 700 |
| Sting | National | YTD | 500 |
| Pepsi | National | YTD | 1000 |
| Lays | National | YTD | 1600 |

```
                  Table 2
```

| Product | Geography | Time | Cat Dollar Sales | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sting | Region 1 | 1 Week | 1000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | Region 1 | 1 Week | 2000 | CSD |
| Lays | Region 1 | 1 Week | 5000 | Chips |
| Sting | Region 2 | 1 Week | 2000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | Region 2 | 1 Week | 3000 | CSD |
| Lays | Region 2 | 1 Week | 7000 | Chips |
| Sting | National | 1 Week | 10000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | National | 1 Week | 20000 | CSD |
| Lays | National | 1 Week | 32000 | Chips |
| Sting | Region 1 | YTD | 1000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | Region 1 | YTD | 2000 | CSD |
| Lays | Region 1 | YTD | 5000 | Chips |
| Sting | Region 2 | YTD | 2000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | Region 2 | YTD | 3000 | CSD |
| Lays | Region 2 | YTD | 7000 | Chips |
| Sting | National | YTD | 5000 | Energy |
| Pepsi | National | YTD | 10000 | CSD |
| Lays | National | YTD | 16000 | Chips |

**Problem:**
I need to calculate Fair Share Index (share of product in a region/ share of its cat in the same region), which is essentially division of ratios. The first part will have the Product Sales(Dollar Sales) in a Geography for a Time Period divided by Product Sales at National level from Table 1. The second part will have the Category Sales (Cat Dollar Sales) in the same Geography for same Time Period divided by Category Sales at the National Level from Table 2

**I need a new Measure in Table 1 with this formula:**
`For each row:`
`Index = [ (Table 1 row[Dollar Sales] / Table 1 [Dollar Sales] where [Geography] ==     "National" & [Time] ==    row[Time] & [Prod] = row[Prod]) /`
`(Table 2 row [Cat Dollar Sales] / Table 2 [Cat Dollar Sales] where Geography == "National") ] * 100`

**Example:**
Consider the Bold and Italicized Row in above Table 1. The calculation will be as follows,

`Fair Share Index = [ (100/500) / (1000/10000)) ] * 100`
`= [ (0.2) / (0.1) ] * 100`
`= 200%`

**What I have Tried:**

I have joined the Tables in the Data Model on Product Column with Many to Many cardinality and Table 1 filters Table 2.

I have tried implementing several type of DAX queries but everything throws an error. I'm new to PowerBI especially DAX. I have done the same in Python with no issues. So any pointers on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You say that you "*need a new Measure in Table 1*", "*For each row*", which would imply you in fact require a Calculated Column, not a Measure. Can you confirm?

Comment: Also, do neither of your tables contain an index column? If so, I'm not sure how it will be possible for any solution to 'know' that each row within Table1 is to be considered 'paired' with the corresponding row position from Table2. Suggest you add index columns to both tables if you haven't already, or else some alternative unique identifier (for example, a concatenation of the Product, Geography and Time fields).